# Setting up neo4j with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, documentation, cypher

I need a step-by-step guide to setting up neo4j to work with a website using javascript/jquery (maybe node.js?).

Do I need this:
https://github.com/neo-technology/neo4js

or this:
https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

I want to use it as a backend server to a website, using the cypher language to manipulate the graph database itself. I dont need help with general graph db layout or the cypher language, just how to make it work(!) from a website environment.

I really need some help with this

Comment: This question is very broad, try focusing an a particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out for a comprehensive tutorial:

https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-movies-template

And this for a single page app using only jquery

https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo

And this for a simplistic node.js app

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/node-neo4j-template